# Using both safety PLC and safety relay

Tags: safety, plc, robotics

I am in the process of designing a robotic cell. This contains a safety door and several e-stops. I want to use the safety PLC from siemens S7-1200F. I need to have two roller tracks with 8 24V motors (3A starting current and 2.5 A rated current) connected by the safety PLC. Separately, there should also be 4 cables to the Fanuc R-30iB robot controller from the safety PLC, 2 for catogory 0 stop (hard stop) and 2 for catogory 1 (soft stop). I connect my fencing so that it activates the soft stop of the robot.

Now my question: can I also use outputs from the safety PLC to switch safety relays, which in turn switch off the DC motors of the roller tracks? This would save a considerable amount of money and I don't see now what the advantage is of connecting all this directly to the modules of the S7-1200. Also, it there a problem with wiring to the Fanuc controller from the Safety PLC (similar problem)?

Comment: Your fencing should trigger the hard-stop on the robot. Fencing "open" means person in cell - therefore hard-stop. Maintenace personel is required to close the cell then or you can include a override-switch within the cell. For the Motors: There are Motor-Driver DO modules capeable of 6A per channel - also as safety ratey version. I Would use these on a remoteIO station.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent, I don't think I've ever worked with a customer that would be ok with closing someone inside a robot cell. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: @Icecl Coming from an automation background working for a well know german automotive company under german labour safety rules, all i can add: Fencing breached -> hard stop. Maintenance runs the cell on 10% max. speed from inside (teaching, repairs, etc...) if required, or from the outside (option of choice) at X%. All personell is trained to german standards and a backup person always has its hand on the e-stop.

Comment: I've read that a catogory 1 stop, controlled stop is enough for the fencing, I use catogory 0 stop for the e-stops.

Unfortunately, I haven't really found the answer I was looking for yet. Is it possible to connect the sensors to the DI and use the DO of the safety PLC to switch a safety relay. I then mount the power supply through these relays. 
Another question, do I mount the E-stops and the fence switches through the safety PLC and onto the fanuc controller? Or do I connect the wires in parallel, to the Safety PLC DI and to the inputs of the Fanuc controller?